# Tensorflow crashes when running with CUDA support

Tags: python, tensorflow

I had an install of tensorflow 2.4.1 and everything worked but I was having issues with it crashing when trying to use Tensorboard. I had a look on github issues page and one of the maintainers said that it's a known issue and will be fixed in 2.5.

So I went and installed 2.5-rc and then everything broke down. I then tried to downgrade back to 2.4.1 but the issue persisted. No other attempts resulted in fixing crashes.

I went all the way to remove Anaconda install, all Python source folders, CUDA and CuDNN installs, then re-installed all back.

As per TF help page I installed TF-2.4.1 with CUDA 11.0 and CuDNN 8.0. It actually worked until I installed CUDA. Now it crashes every time even when I manually hide CUDA-enable devices. This is the output I get:

```
2021-05-06 21:52:41.777148: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-05-06 21:52:41.777782: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-05-06 21:52:41.808730: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.402GHz coreCount: 30 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 268.26GiB/s
2021-05-06 21:52:41.809006: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-05-06 21:52:41.812511: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-05-06 21:52:41.812659: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-05-06 21:52:41.814721: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-05-06 21:52:41.815428: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-05-06 21:52:41.819782: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-05-06 21:52:41.821370: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-05-06 21:52:41.822198: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-05-06 21:52:41.822393: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-05-06 21:52:41.822962: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-05-06 21:52:41.882108: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.402GHz coreCount: 30 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 268.26GiB/s
2021-05-06 21:52:41.882425: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-05-06 21:52:41.882571: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-05-06 21:52:41.882712: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-05-06 21:52:41.882855: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-05-06 21:52:41.883245: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-05-06 21:52:41.883438: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-05-06 21:52:41.883648: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-05-06 21:52:41.883842: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-05-06 21:52:41.884084: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-05-06 21:52:42.347207: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-05-06 21:52:42.347408: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0 
2021-05-06 21:52:42.347499: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N 
2021-05-06 21:52:42.347777: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 4733 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6)
2021-05-06 21:52:42.359614: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-05-06 21:52:42.777774: I tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:136] Profiler session initializing.
2021-05-06 21:52:42.777956: I tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:155] Profiler session started.
2021-05-06 21:52:42.778158: I tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1365] Profiler found 1 GPUs
2021-05-06 21:52:42.780165: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cupti64_110.dll
2021-05-06 21:52:42.846459: I tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:172] Profiler session tear down.
2021-05-06 21:52:42.846657: I tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1487] CUPTI activity buffer flushed
Epoch 1/20
2021-05-06 21:52:43.007415: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
2021-05-06 21:52:43.367381: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-05-06 21:52:43.921448: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-05-06 21:52:43.927001: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

Anyone knows what can be the issue?

Comment: you have to make sure that the path to the CUPTI libraries is in your PATH variable.  There are other questions here that cover this, if you want to search for them.

Comment: @RobertCrovella actually, I just noticed and fixed CUPTI errors, see updated output. This doesn't fix the main problem though.

Answer (score 1):

Almost every version of Tensorflow has it's specific version of CUDA and CUDNN.
If you have Tensorflow 2.5, you need CUDA 11.2 and CUDNN 8.1https://spltech.co.uk/how-to-install-tensorflow-2-5-with-cuda-11-2-and-cudnn-8-1-for-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem before, and there of many issues to cause this error code.
but
I recommend for install TensorFlow, follow the version that exists in the GPU section in [enter link description here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows)

and you can watch these video [enter link description here](https://youtu.be/1QTgf3svtQw)

> Note: before going into reinstalling, try

```
import tensorflow as tf

physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
```